# prevent authentication for users with a certain status

Tags: feathersjs, feathers-authentication

I have started a very simple app using the feathers generator. I would like to how I can add a hook to the authentication endpoint to prevent a user from logging in if their status is set to 'blocked'.

I know how to create hooks on the users service, but I think I would like this hook to be on the authenticate service, and Im not quite sure where to do this.

Thanks

Comment: You can hook authentication.create - the user is part of hook.result and throw NotAuthenticated there if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by implementing a custom strategy ([doc](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/local.html#customization))

Let say you working with the local strategy (email + password)

Then you can do something like this:

```
const { AuthenticationService, JWTStrategy } = require('@feathersjs/authentication');
const { NotAuthenticated } = require('@feathersjs/errors');
const { LocalStrategy } = require('@feathersjs/authentication-local');

    // Extend the LocalStrategy
    class CustomLocalStrategy extends LocalStrategy {
      async authenticate(authentication, params) {
        let resp;

        // Normal authentication
        try {
          resp = await super.authenticate(authentication, params);
        } catch (e) {
          if (e instanceof NotAuthenticated) {
            throw new NotAuthenticated('Not authenticated', {
              reason: 'invalid'
            });
          }
        }

        // Check if user is blocked, blocked should be a bool in the user model
        if (resp.user.blocked) {
          throw new NotAuthenticated('Not authenticated', {
            reason: 'blocked'
          });
        }

        return resp;
      }
    }

    // Register the strategy
    module.exports = app => {
      const authentication = new AuthenticationService(app);
      authentication.register('local', new CustomLocalStrategy());
      app.use('/authentication', authentication);
    };
```